# How to find where query is triggered [Django]

Tags: django, database, query-optimization

How can I profile a query and find where it is triggered to optimize it? I'm trying to use django toolbar but it doesn't show which function is triggering the query so I don't know where to fix.

Comment: That's a good question.  I generally use `cProfile`, but I'd love to know if there's a more direct way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]You can go to the function that is calling the query by clicking on the plus on the left side of the query, using django debug_toolbar